# Chrome app : ajax request external script : getting net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I get an error on my ajax call in my chrome packaged app :

> net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Is there a way to fix this problem on client side (in chrome app in my ajax call) or in server side ?

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://remote_IP/myscript.php",
    type : "GET",
    crossDomain : true,
    cache : false,
    data: {
        login:login,
        password:pwd
    },
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(json)
    {
        var status = json.status;
        if(status == "NOK")
        {
            cb('error');
        }
        else
        {
            cb('true');
        }
    },
    error : function error(jsonError, ts,et)
    {
        ajaxError(jsonError, ts,et,cb);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a problem with the server.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem here is that chrome won't acknowledge https from an IP address.

The browser expects that valid SSL certificates are generated for a domain name rather than the IP.

Try using SSL from [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) or [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com/) with a domain name and try again.